# Reading string from Delphi InternetReadFile

Tags: php, json, delphi

I'm sending a JSON query to my PHP page.

Since I have been having trouble with the JSON part on the server (I'm new to JSON).

I decided to simply have the server send it back so I could see it.

Here is the JSON text I sent to it and therefore expected it to send back to me (yes, it contains dummy data):

```
{"propertyType":"Detached","price":"edtPrice","bedrooms":"2","bathrooms":"2","squareFeet":"1200","address":"edtAddr","city":"edtCity","postal":"edtPostal","agentPhone":"edtAgent","agentEMail":"edtEMail","agentName":"edtAgent","agentCompany":"edtCompany","Pictures":[]}
```

I have confirmed this is what was sent to the server and it has no #0's in the uploaded data.

Here is the code that receives it and sends it back to the client:

```
<?

if (file_get_contents('php://input')) {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo $json;

$parsedJSON = json_decode($json);
// (error here)  echo $parsedJSON->city;
}

?>
```

Here's the Delphi (XE3) code that receives the reply from the POST to the server:

```
      bRet:= HttpSendRequest(hRequest,
                             nil,
                             0,
                             PChar(sData),
                             length(sData));
      // choosing Unicode here as the format
      ss:=TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.Unicode);
      try
        repeat
          if not InternetReadFile(hRequest, @caBuffer, SizeOf(caBuffer), iBytesRead) then
            RaiseLastOSError;

          ss.WriteBuffer(caBuffer, iBytesRead);
        until iBytesRead = 0;

        Result:=ss.DataString;
      finally
        ss.Free;
      end;
```

upon receiving it back from the server, it looks like the encoding is ambiguous.  i wouldn't be surprised to see unicode encoding coming back from the server but i don't know what to do with this text...

caBuffer contains:

```
(10, 123, 0, 34, 0, 112, 0, 114, 0, 105, 0, 99, 0, 101, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 101, 0, 100, 0, 116, 0, 80, 0, 114, 0, 105, 0, 99, 0, 101, 0, 34, 0, 44, 0, 34, 0, 98, 0, 101, 0, 100, 0, 114, 0, 111, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 115, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 50, 0, 34, 0, 44, 0, 34, 0, 98, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 104, 0, 114, 0, 111, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 115, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 50, 0, 34, 0, 44, 0, 34, 0, 115, 0, 113, 0, 117, 0, 97, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 70, 0, 101, 0, 101, 0, 116, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 49, 0, 50, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 34, 0, 44, 0, 34, 0, 97, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 115, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 101, 0, 100, 0, 116, 0, 65, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 114, 0, 34, 0, 44, 0, 34, 0, 99, 0, 105, 0, 116, 0, 121, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 101, 0, 100, 0, 116, 0, 67, 0, 105, 0, 116, 0, 121, 0, 34, 0, 44, 0, 34, 0, 112, 0, 111, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 97, 0, 108, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 101, 0, 100, 0, 116, 0, 60, 98, 62, 69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 58, 60, 47, 98, 62, 32, 91, 56, 93, 32, 84, 114, 121, 105, 110, 103, 32, 116, 111, 32, 103, 101, 116, 32, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 32, 111, 102, 32, 110, 111, 110, 45, 111, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 60, 98, 114, 62, 51, 60, 98, 114, 62, 51, 13, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 84, 241, 24, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 208, 153, 241, 113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 241, 24, 0, 76, 18, 7, 0, 90, 253, 160, 93, 4, 241, 24, 0, 250, 98, 65, 117, 76, 18, 7, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 44, 144, 47, 1, 208, 153, 241, 113, 205, 171, 186, 220, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 153, 241, 113, 20, 241, 24, 0, 48, 241, 24, 0, 48, 2, 72, 117, 130, 13, 184, 93, 124, 241, 24, 0, 145, 109, 65, 117, 104, 241, 24, 0, 34, 34, 83, 0, 139, 1, 0, 0, 200, 241, 24, 0, 156, 243, 24, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 112, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 233, 108, 65, 117, 145, 109, 65, 117, 233, 130, 64, 0, 136, 156, 46, 1, 173, 126, 64, 0, 1, 241, 24, 0, 144, 206, 37, 1, 117, 125, 64, 0, 224, 13, 47, 1, 47, 128, 64, 0, 183, 14, 37, 0, 224, 13, 47, 1, 128, 128, 64, 0, 144, 206, 37, 1, 48, 210, 80, 0, 56, 210, 80, 0, 144, 206, 37, 1, 160, 156, 46, 1, 99, 24, 83, 0, 192, 241, 24, 0, 122, 24, 83, 0, 130, 24, 83, 0, 108, 242, 24, 0, 140, 24, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 183, 14, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 206, 37, 1, 216, 241, 24, 0, 58, 93, 76, 0, 139, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 242, 24, 0, 250, 98, 65, 117, 172, 17, 79, 0, 139, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 183, 14, 37, 0, 205, 171, 186, 220, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 183, 14, 37, 0, 20, 242, 24, 0, 48, 242, 24, 0, 48, 2, 72, 117, 144, 206, 37, 1, 124, 242, 24, 0, 145, 109, 65, 117, 81, 109, 65, 117, 191, 255, 160, 93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 172, 17, 79, 0, 152, 31, 51, 1, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 184, 253, 126, 88, 242, 24, 0, 213, 98, 66, 117, 64, 170, 158, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 196, 242, 24, 0, 0, 184, 253, 126, 152, 31, 51, 1, 172, 17, 79, 0, 132, 242, 24, 0, 153, 203, 55, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 196, 242, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 184, 253, 126, 152, 31, 51, 1, 196, 242, 24, 0, 232, 109, 65, 117, 242, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 87, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 81, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 164, 174, 47, 1, 213, 62, 66, 0, 164, 174, 47, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 213, 100, 64, 0, 204, 242, 24, 0, 37, 177, 64, 0, 136, 174, 46, 1, 24, 175, 46, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0, 64, 10, 48, 1, 32, 175, 46, 1, 130, 100, 64, 0, 26, 179, 64, 0, 28, 175, 46, 1, 122, 167, 64, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 118, 247, 65, 0, 24, 175, 46, 1, 28, 175, 46, 1, 89, 166, 64, 0, 136, 174, 46, 1, 152, 22, 64, 0, 189, 125, 64, 0, 116, 117, 64, 0, 24, 175, 46, 1, 130, 100, 64, 0, 249, 115, 64, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 61, 123, 64, 0, 234, 116, 64, 0, 247, 116, 64, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 100, 64, 0, 192, 149, 64, 0, 151, 160, 64, 0, 76, 10, 48, 1, 240, 174, 46, 1, 130, 100, 64, 0, 26, 179, 64, 0, 236, 174, 46, 1, 122, 167, 64, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 118, 247, 65, 0, 232, 174, 46, 1, 236, 174, 46, 1, 89, 166, 64, 0, 144, 166, 46, 1, 152, 22, 64, 0, 189, 125, 64, 0, 116, 117, 64, 0, 232, 174, 46, 1, 130, 100, 64, 0, 249, 115, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

If I handle it like Unicode, I get this.

```
笊∀瀀爀椀挀攀∀㨀∀攀搀琀倀爀椀挀攀∀Ⰰ∀戀攀搀爀漀漀洀猀∀㨀∀㈀∀Ⰰ∀戀愀琀栀爀漀漀洀猀∀㨀∀㈀∀Ⰰ∀猀焀甀愀爀攀䘀攀攀琀∀㨀∀'#$3100'㈀　　∀Ⰰ∀愀搀搀爀攀猀猀∀㨀∀攀搀琀䄀搀搀爀∀Ⰰ∀挀椀琀礀∀㨀∀攀搀琀䌀椀琀礀∀Ⰰ∀瀀漀猀琀愀氀∀㨀∀攀搀琀㰀㹢牅潲㩲⼼㹢嬠崸吠祲湩'#$2067'潴朠瑥瀠潲数瑲⁹景渠湯漭橢捥㱴牢㌾
```

What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: 123, 0 is { and 34, 0 is " in UTF-16, so the question is, what is that stray 10 at the start of the buffer? And why are you sending UTF-16 rather than UTF-8?

Comment: But the tail end of the buffer is not text. Frankly, if you want to make progress you need to determine, from first principles, what you are sending. Don't try to reverse it, using trial and error. Make sure you understand what you are transmitting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thank you for all your work in stack overflow; some very good answers, sir.  i changed it to use TidHttp.Post(url, stream) and that helped a lot.  now instead of no documents working, just the large ones break.  I don't have time to come back to this for probably a few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

`php://input` will provide you with the entire packet of data transmitted to the server not just the contents. This will include the headers as well.

I am not a Delphi expert but my guess is you are not sending the JSON as you think.

As far as I know this should not happen, but I am mentioning it anyway: The data you get might be archived if compression was used, but as I mentioned this should not be the case.

Unless you get a nice headers + content data it means the wrong data was sent.

Comment: oh, that is good to know.  i am new to JSON.  i'll need to leave this for now.  thank you for your help!